# <!DOCTYPE html> causes header and footer to break

Tags: css, html, doctype

I have a document with a header and a footer. Instead of using `position:fixed`, I'm using 3 divs, with the center div scrolling instead of the document. Below is my code:

```
<style> 
html{ 
    overflow:hidden; 
    font-size: 80px;
} 
.content{ 
    display:block; 
    top:10%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
    width:100%; 
    height:80%; 
} 
.header{position:absolute;top:0;} 
.footer{position:absolute;top:90%;} 
</style> 
<div class="header">Hover</div> 
<div class="content"> 
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
    lorem ipsum <br />
</div> 
<div class="footer">Hover</div>
```

this works as expected, but if I add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to turn on HMTL5 standards mode, the website breaks (the page scrolls instead, and the header and footer scroll with it, rather than being fixed).

Is there any issues with my code, or is there a more standard way of what I want to do? (without using position:fixed which doesn't work when I compile my site to android)

Comment: you may need to add `html, body {height:100%}`

Comment: Please, use indents (especially when you share your work with others).

Comment: as Pete said you need to set the height of `html` and `body` otherwise the `body` has the height of the content so `%` height and position would not work, for the elements in the `body` in the way you would expect.

Comment: @mohammad-areeb-siddiqui I can't use JSFiddle since that sets the page to html5 standards mode.

Comment: @Pete yep setting the document height to 100% seems to have fixed it. If you want to make an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically using HTML5 standards made, the document will stretch to fit the content, and having the content be a percentage of the body would mean nothing since the document has already stretched to accommodate it.

By explicitly saying `html, body {height:100%}` you can tell the browser to not resize the document, and then specifying it based on percentage will make sense.

(Thanks to @Pete and @t.niese who provided the answer, but just did so in a comment)

Answer (score -1):

Use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute` , but then you also have to add the proper meta tag for it to work: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=100%; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1; user-scalable=no;" />`

Adjust accordingly...

Comment: I have almost the identical meta tag, only difference is my width is device-width instead of 100%. The header works for the most part, but as soon as elements are shown/hidden, it breaks.